# Deleting rows that contain a the same a values as a different row but in different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table that looks like this.

```
+------+------+------------+
| emp1 | emp2 | year_hired |
+------+------+------------+
| Tom  | Mark |       2017 |
| Mark | Tom  |       2017 |
| Tom  | Eve  |       2017 |
| Eve  | Mark |       2017 |
| Eve  | Tom  |       2017 |
| Mark | Eve  |       2017 |
| Alex | Jane |       2015 |
| Jane | Alex |       2015 |
+------+------+------------+
```

I want to delete rows such that the resulting table will contain combinations of employees instead of permutations like so:

```
+------+------+------------+
| emp1 | emp2 | year_hired |
+------+------+------------+
| Tom  | Mark |       2017 |
| Tom  | Eve  |       2017 |
| Eve  | Mark |       2017 |
| Alex | Jane |       2015 |
+------+------+------------+
```

How can this be done? Please explain your answer if you can. I'm using MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DELETE with a selfjoin. On "duplicates" keep the row where the names are sorted alphabetically (emp1 < emp2).

```
delete t2
from tbl t1
join tbl t2
  on  t2.emp1 = t1.emp2
  and t2.emp2 = t1.emp1
  and t2.year_hired = t1.year_hired -- optional?
where t1.emp1 < t1.emp2;
```

After that the table will contain:

```
| emp1 | emp2 | year_hired |
| ---- | ---- | ---------- |
| Mark | Tom  | 2017       |
| Eve  | Mark | 2017       |
| Eve  | Tom  | 2017       |
| Alex | Jane | 2015       |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j25ZCR6xzXiyUvkHX1pPR9/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function in a query to join to the table:

```
delete t
from tablename t inner join (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by least(emp1, emp2), greatest(emp1, emp2), year_hired) rn
  from tablename
) r on (r.emp1, r.emp2, r.year_hired) = (t.emp1, t.emp2, t.year_hired)
where r.rn > 1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4dhkDZqe2zRhdKEiQzQvae/0).
Results:

```
| emp1 | emp2 | year_hired |
| ---- | ---- | ---------- |
| Tom  | Mark | 2017       |
| Tom  | Eve  | 2017       |
| Eve  | Mark | 2017       |
| Alex | Jane | 2015       |
```